# FPDF and text wrappig OUTSIDE of cells

Tags: php, pdf

Everyone, been using FPDF, and would like to render a multicell with some text in it that the rest of the text on the page wraps around.  As it is, if I render a log multicell ad position it on the right of the page, it shows up, but the text won't begin until the cell is finished.  I've done a good amount of searching and can't quite work out a way to make this work.  Ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you have to use multicell in fpdf so you can wrap your data i n one column

```
$pdf->SetXY(10,40);
$pdf->MultiCell(100,7 , "".$row['data'] ,1,'L',false);
```

it is helpfull